# React. You can now view Local: at: http://localhost:3000. But sometimes does not On Your Network: http: //192.168 X.XXXX:YYYY

Tags: reactjs, webpack

React
You can now view
Local: http://localhost:3000.
But sometimes does not view
On Your Network: http: //192.168.1.246:3000
What to do, If you want to see markup on another devises in the same network

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --hot --host 0.0.0.0
```

If you are prompted to install something, do it.

```
Otherwise
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
or
yarn add webpack-cli --dev
will install it
```

If after installation it will offer

```
 npm audit fix
```

do it.

That is all.